# Running project in command prompt

Tags: java

I am running project in netbeans, and I want to run the same project on command prompt...

But during compilation the message comes

> Note : filename.java uses or overrides
>   a deprecated API
>
> Note : Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details.

How can I compile and run the project in command prompt?
How can I remove this problem please tell me...

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the command prompt:

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation filename.java
```

The message is telling you that you are using a deprecated API. A deprecated API means an API that you shouldn't be using because it has been replaced by something else. The code will still work for now but someday a future release may eliminate the deprecated API and then your code will break. It is a good idea to stay away from deprecated APIs. The message is telling you to invoke javac with the -Xlint:deprecation flag and it will tell you exactly what it is complaining about.

Note: even if you get this warning message when you compile, you can ignore it - your program still compiles and works.

Comment: It's worth noting that a deprecation warning isn't an error.  Yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well try using the following annotation:

`@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`

> **@SuppressWarnings**—the
>   @SuppressWarnings annotation **tells the
>   compiler to suppress specific warnings**
>   that it would otherwise generate. In
>   the example below, a deprecated method
>   is used and the compiler would
>   normally generate a warning. In this
>   case, however, the annotation causes
>   the warning to be suppressed.

```
   // use a deprecated method and tell 
   // compiler not to generate a warning
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void useDeprecatedMethod() {
        objectOne.deprecatedMethod(); //deprecation warning - suppressed
    }
```

But you might end up leaving the deprecated code there forever. Best is for you to consider using the new API.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans by default will create an Ant project (although you can use Apache Maven, as well, with NetBeans). If you see a file named "build.xml" in your folder, then you should build with:

```
ant
```

If you see a file named "pom.xml" in your project folder, then you should build with:

```
mvn package
```

The warning message that you see is not an error, meaning that it did compile successfully, but you should probably deal with the warnings, since they indicate that you are using deprecated features. As to executing your project, simply invoke the java command with your JAR file. For example:

```
java -jar build/myproject.jar
```

Typically the resulting JAR is placed in the "build" directory; you will need to replace "build/myproject.jar" with the name of the actual JAR file. For some projects, the output directory may differ.